# Spring 3 configure ResponseStatusExceptionResolver warnLoggerCategory to use log4j?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring 3.2.x, I'm trying to configure the ResponseStatusExceptionResolver to specify a warnLoggerCategory, but am unable to understand how to configure this.

I have created the following JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResponseStatusExceptionResolver responseStatusExceptionResolver(){
        ResponseStatusExceptionResolver resolver = new ResponseStatusExceptionResolver();
        resolver.setWarnLogCategory("org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.warnLogger");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

However, if I put a breakpoint in the resolver, when it is called by Spring (due to an exception being thrown), I see that the resolver is a different object than the one created in my JavaConfig.  Which I interpret to mean that I am not configuring the Resolver properly, or not setting it in the right place.

Am i missing something in my JavaConfig for Spring to use this Resolver instead of the default one it uses?  The WebMVC configuration was started in XML configuration, but I'm slowly trying to migrate everything to JavaConfig.  Currently, it is as follows:

webmvc-config.xml:

```
<!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.iaa"  use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods 
    Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService" />

<!-- secure all controllers with method annotation -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<mvc:resources location="/js/, /, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/, /WEB-INF/views/tiles/, /WEB-INF/views/templates/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static 
    resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- Register "global" interceptor beans to apply to all registered HandlerMappings -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"      p:paramName="lang" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure" />

<!-- Resolves localized messages*.properties and application.properties 
    files in the application to allow for internationalization. The messages*.properties 
    files translate Roo generated messages which are part of the admin interface, 
    the application.properties resource bundle localizes all application specific 
    messages such as entity names and menu items. -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />

<!-- Store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
    id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale" />

<!-- Resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to 
    allow for theme support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"  id="themeSource" />

<!-- Store preferred theme configuration in a cookie -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
    id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard" />

<!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical 
    - view names for error views. The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet 
    - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: this will happen 
    - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Enable this for integration of file upload functionality -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    id="multipartResolver" />

<!-- Tiles page resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" >
    <property name="cache" value="false"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="tilesInitializer">
        <bean class="com.iaa.system.tiles3.TilesInitializer" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.ia.web.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean"    id="applicationConversionService" />
```

Comment: You have javaconfig so I assume you have a class with `@EnableWebMvc` somewhere. Let this class extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and override the `configureHandlerExceptionResolvers` and add your resolver to the list.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I'm not sure what "this class" refers to in "Let this class extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`".  What is "this class"?  Additionally, I actually don't have `@EnableWebMvc`, but am using XML configuration for that at the moment (webmvc-config.xml).  I checked the config file, and do have a bean defined for `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`, but nothing for a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.  I've edited the question and added the contents of my webmvc-config.xml file.

Comment: As stated I assumed you are using full javaconfig and aren't mixing and matching. But apparently you are using the namespace and xml and thus are mixing and matching. With this class I was referring to the class with `@EnableWebMvc` which you don't have. But to answer your question, on your configured `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` set the `order` property to something lower then 1.